# Backward compatibility of Apache2 modules

Tags: apache, ubuntu, centos, fedora

Does an `rpm` or `deb` package which contains an `apache2` module that was compiled against Apache 2.4 likely work on a system that has Apache 2.2, or is this asking for trouble? I'm not worried about the config files, just the shared object `mod_foo.so` .

Comment: You'll almost certainly get the error message mentioned here, or something like it: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/FAQ#Why_am_I_getting_.22module_module-name_is_not_compatible_with_this_version_of_Apache.22_messages_in_my_error_log.3F

Comment: Thanks! I had never heard of MMN, good to know. Is there an easy way to display the MMN of my `mod_foo.so` file?